# clicking/typing on UITextField increments UIPageViewController instead of displaying keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using UIPageViewController to show View Controllers that are on my storyboard on the screen, when I put a UITextField on the view controller that I've put on the UIPageViewController and when I run te app and I click on the UITextField, the screen jumps to the next screen instead of just popping up the keyboard or when you type something in the `UITextField`, it also jumps to the next screen. I've made a simple sample project which you can download here: http://www.2shared.com/file/VNF3DO-g/pageScroll.html use iPhone simulator and click on the UITextField and you'll see it will jump to the next view instead of popping up the keyboard.

Comment: You ever find a solution/workaround?

Comment: I've made test with Xcode 5 template `Page-Based Application`, add UITextView on DataViewController's view and it works fine: tap on text view open keyboard without page turning.