# UIPageViewController bug with UITextField and keyboard showing

Tags: ios, ios6

So I'm trying to find a workaround for this bizarre bug:
http://www.screencast.com/t/UqvVn8ccodEV

Basically I have a UIPageViewController with sub view controllers (obviously). Once I add a text field, it does this weird thing where if you scroll it and then click a text field, it randomly moves to another page. None of the delegates get called, and the keyboard moves up and down again.

Seems like the same thing as here: [clicking/typing on UITextField increments UIPageViewController instead of displaying keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804702/clicking-typing-on-uitextfield-increments-uipageviewcontroller-instead-of-displa#comment24327396_15804702)

Also seems to be recorded here: http://openradar.appspot.com/13315308

Can't figure out what the hell this would be, or a way around it.

### Edit

Here is a skeleton version (pulled from the linked question):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6l5efem3wque7li/pageScroll.zip?v=1mci

Scroll one page, then hit the textfield. Only happens the first time around.

Comment: Very weird indeed. Does this happen on a totally basic skeleton of what you are working on? If you're not sure - try out the basic scenario and post your findings.

Comment: Yes. This is the code from that other question which is a basic skeleton demonstrating the problem. Pulled it off whatever awful download service he was using: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6l5efem3wque7li/pageScroll.zip?v=1mci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this voodoo out: Embed your `UITextField` within a `UIScrollView`. I tried it on the project you referred to and it worked.

I guess it has something to do with changing the responder chain that messes things up.

Comment: Hmm.. Wonder if there is a way to fix the responder chain directly then.

Comment: This smells like a bug, wouldn't count on a straightforward way to get around it.

Comment: Does seem to work. Super odd. Hey thanks! At least for the moment I don't have to completely eschew UIPageViewController.